# python - top matches between nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data structure of playlists:

```
users={
  'playlist1': {'Karma Police': 2.0,'Bittersweet Symphony': 3.0,'The Queen Is Dead':4.0,'Song 1': 1.0},
  'playlist2': {'Bittersweet Symphony': 1.0,'Karma Police': 1.0,'The Queen Is Dead': 7.0,'Song 2': 1.0 },
  'playlist3': {'Karma Police': 4.0,'Bittersweet Symphony': 4.0,'The Queen Is Dead':3.0,'Song 3': 1.0}
       }
```

which is being passed to this function:

```
def sim_distance(users,playlist1,playlist2):
  '''
  Returns a distance-based similarity score for 
  playlist1 and playlist2
  '''  
  # Get the list of shared_items
  si={}
  for item in users[playlist1]:
    if item in users[playlist2]:
        si[item]=1
  # if they have no ratings in common, return 0
  if len(si)==0: return 0
  # Add up the squares of all the differences
  sum_of_squares=sum([pow(users[playlist1][item]-users[playlist2][item],2)
                          for item in users[playlist1] if item in users[playlist2]])
  return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)

#print sim_distance(users, 'playlist1', 'playlist2')
```

lastly, the above `function` is part of another one:

```
def topMatches(users,playlist,n=2,similarity=sim_distance):

  '''
   Returns the best matches for user from 
   the prefs dictionary.
   Number of results and similarity function 
   are optional params.
  '''

  scores=[(similarity(users,playlist,other),other)
                       for other in users if other!=playlist]
# Sort the list so the highest scores appear at the top 
  scores.sort( )
  scores.reverse( )
  return scores[0:n]
```

`topMatches(users, 'playlist1')`

prints:`[(0.14285714285714285, 'playlist3'), (0.06666666666666667, 'playlist2')]`

**but If I have a much more nested structure, like so:**

```
playlists_user1={'user1':[
               {'playlist1A':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'Karma Police','artist': 'Radiohead', 'count': 1.0},
                    {'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony','artist': 'The Verve','count': 2.0},  
                    {'name': 'Song 1a','artist': 'Band 1a','count': 2.0}                  
                     ]
                    }
               },
               {'playlist1B':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'We Will Rock You','artist': 'Queen', 'count': 3.0},
                    {'name': 'Roxanne','artist': 'Police','count': 5.0},
                    {'name': 'Song 1b','artist': 'Band 1b','count': 2.0}                     
                     ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }   
playlists_user2={'user2':[
               {'playlist2A':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'Karma Police','artist': 'Radiohead', 'count': 1.0},
                    {'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony','artist': 'The Verve','count': 4.0},
                    {'name': 'Song 2a','artist': 'Band 2a','count': 2.0}                      
                     ]
                    }
               },
               {'playlist2B':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'We Will Rock You','artist': 'Queen', 'count': 4.0},
                    {'name': 'Roxanne','artist': 'Police','count': 1.0},
                    {'name': 'Song 2b','artist': 'Band 2b','count': 2.0}                     
                     ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }   
playlists_user3={'user3':[
               {'playlist3A':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'Karma Police','artist': 'Radiohead', 'count': 4.0},
                    {'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony','artist': 'The Verve','count': 6.0},
                    {'name': 'Song 3a','artist': 'Band 3a','count': 1.0}                      
                     ]
                    }
               },
               {'playlist3B':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'We Will Rock You','artist': 'Queen', 'count': 8.0},
                    {'name': 'Roxanne','artist': 'Police','count': 3.0},
                    {'name': 'Song 3b','artist': 'Band 3b','count': 4.0}                     
                     ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
```

**how do I correct**:

**1)** `sim_distance(users,playlist1,playlist2)`

and

**2)** `topMatches(users,playlist,n=2,similarity=sim_distance)`

**in order to adapt my code to this new nested structure?**

**I'm looking for top `matches` for `'playlist1A'` and `'playlist1B'` in `user2` and `user3`, top matches for `'playlist2A'` and `'playlist2B'`in `user1` and `user3` and so forth.**

Comment: `list[:n]` will return the first `n` values.  To get the first two values do `scores[:2]` or `scores[:n+1]`

Comment: What do you think `other` should be?  As it is, `other` is the keys of `prefs`, that is to say "playlist1" and "playlist2"

Comment: `[(similarity(user1,other), other) for other in prefs if other!=user1]` what's `user1` in here? shouldn't it be `user`?

Comment: is prefs the contents of user2? or is that what you've posted? I mean, could you update your question with an example of how you call this functions and with what variables

Comment: @BorysZibrov, please refer to edit. I've posted the function call for you.

Comment: Where does this information ever get used? `user2 = {'Bitter Sweet Symphony': 1.0, 'Sonnet': 4.0, 'We Are The Champions': 4.0, 'Karma Police': 2.0}`

Comment: @data_garden Come to think of it, I'm not clear exactly what behavior you're looking for. `sum_distance` provides the distance between two USERS, but you seem to be looking for the min distance between two SONGS, based on the fact that you seem to want something like `[x, "Karma Police"]` as your solution. Can you be more clear what you want?

Comment: @data_garden ...I don't understand what you mean. To clarify my previous comment though, `sum_distance` gives you a score which depends on ALL tracks the two users have in common. But you seem to want a list of songs... Do you perhaps want to know which playlist has the best overall score? In that case, it seems both playlists you gave would have a score of 1 (Bitter Sweet Symphony maps to 2.0 and 1.0, difference is 1, squared is 1, and same for Karma Police)...

Comment: @data_garden Hm. Perhaps. But it seems in your second edit that `similarity` is called with 3 arguments. Can you show what the difference is?

Comment: @data_garden Ya gotta help me a little here. I meant, please show the definition for the version og `similarity` which takes 3 arguments.

Comment: You have a few issues in your code. First, note that  `other` in your list comprehension is just the name of the key ('playlist1' and 'playlist2'), so you're comparing the `user1` dictionary to a string. This will always give you zero.
Second, `user1` should have the same structure as `playlist1` or not? Show us an example where `sim_distance` works, because `sim_distance(user1, prefs['playlist1'])` doesn't work as it's supposed to do. The structure is not clear, so we can't guess. Make that work first and we can help you with the `topMatches` question.

Comment: @data_garden No, not quite. In this code: `scores=[(similarity(users,playlist,other),other) for other in users if other!=playlist]`, what is getting called with `similarity(users,playlist,other)`? You're passing 3 arguments, but before you had `similarity=sim_distance` and `sim_distance(user1,user2)` with 2 arguments.

Comment: @B.Eckles I completely re-edited the question, which now starts with a working starting point, stating how I am changing the data structure and what my goal is. sorry for the mess.

Comment: @cd98 see if the edit is now what you need in order to understand the question.

Comment: @data_garden this is becoming a bit painful. Can you please now add a call of `topMatches` (is it over playlists or users?) and the expected output for the nested case? Now I don't know if you want the best match for user1 and user2 (and any playlist would do) or if you want the best match between individual playlists.

In any case, instead of doing a list comprehension, consider iterating over the dictionaries with `for key, value in d.items():` (python 3.x), then you can take `value['key']` if needed. This can be achieved with comprehension, but might clear up the confusion due to nesting.

Comment: I'm lost once again. The nested structure has three `playlist1` (one for each user). Let users be A, B, C. Let's call them `playlist1A`, ..., `playlist1C`, `playlist2A`, ..., `playlist3C`. 9 playlists. How do you define the distance between `playlist1` and `playlist2`?

Comment: then maybe for each playlist in each user we need the top match in all other users's playlists. i.e. for `playlists1A` ignore all other playlists in `user1` and look for matches in `user 2 and 3`,s `playlists`, returning `best match`, or `distance`, for `each`. makes sense?

Comment: Suggested answer posted. Please please please be more careful in your next question. Having a really clear question, data and expected output saves time for everyone. I probably spent more time trying to understand what you wanted than solving it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few assumptions based on the last data you posted.
The code is untested and I had to break from your list comprehension into ugly for loops. The dictionaries were nested in annoying ways so I couldn't make it cleaner

```
import operator


def sim_distance(playlist1, playlist2):
    """
    Returns a distance-based similarity score for 
    playlist1 and playlist2
    """    
    # Flatten playlists
    playlist1, playlist2 = list(playlist1.values())[0], list(playlist2.values())[0]
    sum_of_squares = 0.
    for i in range(len(playlist1['tracks'])):
        for j in range(len(playlist2['tracks'])):
            if playlist1['tracks'][i]['name'] == playlist2['tracks'][j]['name']:
                sum_of_squares += (playlist1['tracks'][i]['count'] - playlist2['tracks'][j]['count'])**2

    # if they have no ratings in common, return 0
    if (sum_of_squares < 10e-10): return 0.

    return 1/(1+sum_of_squares)


def topMatches(users, playlist, n=2, similarity=sim_distance):

    '''
    Returns the best matches for a playlist of a user
    The candidates are all other playlists of others users.
    users is a list of dictionaries.

    This code assumes that each playlist has a different name
    Number of results and similarity function 
    are optional params.
    '''
    playlist_name = list(playlist.keys())[0] 
    scores = {}
    for user in users:
        for other_playlist in list(user.values())[0]:
            other_name = list(other_playlist.keys())[0]
            # Making sure not to compare the playlist with itself
            if  playlist_name != other_name:
                scores[other_name] = sim_distance(playlist, other_playlist)

    # Sort the list so the highest scores appear at the top 
    sorted_scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    sorted_scores.reverse()
    return sorted_scores[0:n]

#Playsts_userX as defined in the question
users = [playlists_user1, playlists_user2, playlists_user3]
test_playlist = {'playlist1A': {'tracks': [{'artist': 'Radiohead',
    'count': 1.0,
    'name': 'Karma Police'},
   {'artist': 'The Verve', 'count': 2.0, 'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony'},
   {'artist': 'Band 1a', 'count': 2.0, 'name': 'Song 1a'}]}}
    topMatches(users, test_playlist, n=8)
```

gives

```
[('playlist2A', 0.07692307692307693),
 ('playlist3A', 0.013157894736842105),
 ('playlist1B', 0.0),
 ('playlist3B', 0.0),
 ('playlist2B', 0.0)]
```

Comment: brilliant. sorry about the mess.

Comment: just one thing. your `test_playlist` does not develop directely from the way `userx_playlists` were built, because it ignores the first `key`:`items`. so I had to build a function to make it work: `def playlistDatabase(id_, index):`// `user_playlist = users[id_]['items'][index]` // `return user_playlist`, so I can pass the result as an arg into `topMatches(users, playlistDatabase(id_=1, index=0), n=8)` and make it mirror `test_playlist` structure.

Comment: but...if I call only `sim_distance()` in this fashion, it always returns `0.0`...shouldn't it include `users` as a third argument?